# C# how to draw line with one pixel width

Tags: c#, graphics

i try to draw line on form:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        Graphics g;

        g = e.Graphics;
        g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
        g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.None;

        Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Red);
        myPen.Width = 1;
        g.DrawLine(myPen, 100, 50, 200, 50);

        g.DrawLine(myPen, 150, 0, 150, 100);
    }
```

it looks like this: [image] but after magnification it looks like this:[image] - line width is 3 pixels ...

my question is: how to draw line width one pixel width ?

ok - i edited it but now it looks like this (in magnification):[image] (wihtout pageunit looks the same)

Comment: C# is a language, you can't draw lines in a language, for that you need a graphical library for rendering to the screen or an image object to render to. The answer will differ a lot depending on what your rendering destination is, with your current tags and description the question can not be answered.

Comment: Trying to use the above example, the lines seem to be drawn without anti-aliasing. Also, there is no black background. Can you supply a minimal reproduction example that works?

Comment: ok 1 edited it but not working ...

Comment: You need to turn off anti-aliasing. Look up the Graphics and the Pen (!!)  properties Pen is a quite surprising beast and will by default connect not pixels but points (between pixels)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is using the following before all your drawing calls:

```
g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;
```

although the example in your question can not be reproduced.

Comment: thans for answer  - i edited my example (sory) but still not woking ...

Comment: Where is that OnPaint event handler? In which component? Also, how do you maximize it (zoom it)? Do you use any kind of software?

Comment: i just override OnPaint metod, and im looking on printscreen in paint (pixel by pixel) but on screen i see it too (directly on very large monitor)

Comment: Unfortunately I can not replicate it.

Comment: Also, the `base.OnPaint(e);` call when I add it in the Form_Paint event handler, it gives me StackOverflowException. Why not to you? It is a WinForms app, right?

Comment: create new C# windows form aplication and paste my code after form1 constructor - in any kind of magnifier you see that line is 3 points width

Comment: don't use onPaint event - just override onPaint metod !

Comment: I did it. Unfortunately it can't be replicated. Perhaps you might need to try it on a brand new .net project in case you have altered something on your form and you don't remember it. Otherwise it might be some kind of a Graphics card trickery which I don't know what. Maybe also the O/S?

Comment: i create new projekt and paste that code after form1 constructor - i do nothing else it working ... os is windows 8.1 on other computers it - the same

Comment: i know reason - i was using windows sreeen DPI Scaling Enchacements (150%) when i turn it off line has 1 pixel width - thanks for help

Comment: Glad to hear it! Please up-vote if the above helped you solve the problem.